# Most REST way for updating record

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Web api 2, at the moment this is how we handle POST, PUT. I don't know if that is the best way, because not having the id in the body of the PUT request is bad? I have validations on the request body, should I validate the id seperately?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/people")
public IHttpActionResult CreatePerson(PersonRequest request)
{

}

[HttpPut]
[Route("api/people/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdatePerson(int id, PersonRequest request)
{

}

public class PersonRequest
{
   public string Name;
   public string LastName;
}
```

How would you do that?

Comment: PersonRequest could have `ID` as a field instead of having to specify it separately

Comment: But when I create a person I dont receive Id

Comment: @S.Peter if you don't return *some* kind of identifier, how are you going to find the proper object to update?

Comment: At the moment we get it from the route binding, which I don't know if this is the proper way

Comment: PUT is usually used to replace the entire resource. I would suggest you keep the is in the url, verify that it is valid, and then compare it to the id in the body before applying update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing seems absolutely right to me.

You are right about `PUT` requests: it is always better to include the resource identifier in the URI. What I would also do is to include it inside the resource representation (the request body), so you may further verify that the user intentions are really to update that specific resource (you should check if `id` from the URI equals `id` from the body).

For your `POST` method I suggest you to return the entire resource representation (including the `id` inside the body), but you do not need to require the user adding an `id` inside the `POST` request body (it could be `null`, `0`, or even missing) if you are assigning it server-side.

Comment: Thanks, I have a few questions, would you use the same request object for both methods? Moreover, how would you validate the Id in the Put method if you take if both from uri and body? Just a simple == operator in the controller action? And why would you return the entire object in the POST?

Comment: I see no problem in using the same object, just do not make the `id` field required for the `POST` action. A simple comparison (`==`) should be enough in the `PUT` action. For the `POST` response I always return the entire object because often there are other properties that are computed server side (e.g. `id` if it is autoincrement). This way the user obtains any data useful for locating the new object (e.g. constructing the URI) and has every property without the need of a new `GET` request.

Comment: Sounds very good, you've already answered my question, and I thank you alot. I have another extra question if you know, I'll be glad: if you happened to experience FluentValidation package and use it, can I somehow have 2 different validators for the request? 1 for the POST and another validator for the PUT?

Comment: From what I remember FluentValidation `Validator`s are bounded to model objects, and not to methods, so you need two different objects. But please create another question because continuing here is entirely off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Peter:
my comments about your design:

1) Id should be included in class PersonRequest

2) so for Create action it should be 0, because it's new object and it will get "next Id value" from DB

3) for Update you need to check if Id > 0 and Id exists in system (in database), else throw exception.

Your new class:

```
public class PersonRequest
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public string LastName;
}
```

4) I would rename class PersonRequest to Person.

Comment: So you suggest both methods will get all the data in the body?

Comment: Yes, it a good place for request details like object PersonRequest/Person

Comment: But isn't it more REST like to set the PUT url to: api/people/4, instead of api/people?